# VisualBasic order List by Property as String

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, reflection, system.reflection

I've got an List of an Custom Class and want to order this List by an Property, but I only have the String of the Property name, becasue I recive this from an javascript.
I tried this with System.Reflection, but it seem, that it isn't working:

```
Dim l As List(Of ActionElement) = New List(Of ActionElement)
'Fill the list
l = l.OrderBy(Function(x) GetType(ActionElement).GetProperty("Designation")).ToList()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you to what you want:

```
Dim l As List(Of ActionElement) = New List(Of ActionElement)
'Fill the list
l = l.OrderBy(Function(x) GetType(ActionElement).GetProperty("Designation").GetValue(x).ToString()).ToList()
```

I would change it slightly to reduce operations to:

```
Dim l As List(Of ActionElement) = New List(Of ActionElement)
Dim sortProperty as PropertyInfo = GetType(ActionElement).GetProperty("Designation")

'Fill the list
l = l.OrderBy(Function(x) sortProperty.GetValue(x).ToString()).ToList()
```